# Java Products Method - multiple rows and columns of products of ints

Tags: java

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1PJm.png) Assume there is already a declared method called products with one int parameter n.
Fill in the body of the products method such that it will return an int[][] with n rows and n columns (i.e., n-by-n) in which the i-th row of the j-th column contains the product (i+1)*(j+1).

EXAMPLE: products(4)[0][0] is 1*1=1, and products(4)[3][3] is 4*4=16.

Sample Input:

5

I have no idea how to even start this problem?

Comment: a. Define an array of size int[n][n]....have a nested for loops iterating from 0 to n , within the inner loop you can calculate the product and store it in int[i][j]

Comment: "Assume there is already a declared method called products with one int parameter n" Start by declaring a method called products and include it in your question.